# How to retrieve a minimum value of a Selenium WebElement in Java?

Tags: java, selenium

I wrote a simple code to refresh a browsergame webpage and to automate tasks on that page with the selenium web browser.

I made a little loop:

```
while (true) {
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Premium Exchange"));
        if (driver.findElement(By.id("premium_exchange_stock_wood") //<-- if the value of the wood stock is 64 or higher){
            driver.findElement(By.name("buy_wood")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.name("buy_wood")).sendKeys("64"); //enter 64 in the 'buy box'
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Calculate best offer ']")).click(); //click calculate best offer
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='premium_exchange']/div/div[2]/button")).click(); //click buy
            Thread.sleep(10000);


        }
```

The page looks like this:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5buIP.png)

Usually the 'Wood' stock is 0. When this stock reaches at least 64, I want my code to execute the if statement, and loop this infinitely. I'm stuck on getting the program to see the value of the webelement as int.. My intention is kind of like this:

If wood_stock is equal to 64 or higher than 64, buy wood, repeat.

Any help would be appreciated! I'm very new to Selenium!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .getText() and parseInt functions

```
String strVal=driver.findElement(By.id("premium_exchange_stock_wood").getText();//gets the value as string
int intVal=Integer.parseInt(strVal);converts string to integer
if (intVal>=64){
  //Perform further actions
}
```

Note: You can use .getAttribute("innerHTML") or .getAttribute("outerHTML") if .getText() does not work